RVO when implicit conversion is happening to the returned value
Consider the following example:
#include <optional>
#include <string>

struct S {
    std::string text = "hello";
};

std::optional<S> foo() {
    S s;
    return s;
}

std::optional<S> bar() {
    S s;
    return std::move(s);
}

Am I correct that foo and bar are identical since the compiler does RVO and automatically moves s when passing it to std::optional<S>?
So the general rule "Don't move what you return" applies also when an implicit conversion will happen?

RVO means something else, but yes, std::move isn't needed here.

std::optional makes RVO a bit more tricky. Here is Jason Turner explaining the issue.

For anything this trivial the compiler will look right through things. And it will optimize almost everything away. std::move in bar is a pessimizing move and you should not do it, it can even break optimization

See this answer that explains the operand of the return statement(if it satisfies some conditions) is rvalue(xvalue) and also the implicit move rule mentioned there.

What you are describing here is not what people usually mean by "RVO" ("return value optimisation"), although that term itself is colloquial and does not appear in the standard.
RVO usually refers to the pre-C++17 situation where a returned prvalue does not get copied:
T f();

T g() { return f(); }

In this example, RVO means that there is no second copy in evaluating g(), and instead the result of f() is constructed directly in the return value of g.
With the adoption of P0135 for C++17 (somewhat misnamed, but widely referred to as "guaranteed copy elision"), this behaviour is now mandatory as of C++17, so there really isn't an "RVO" anymore as an "optimization" — it's just how C++ works now. The key conceptual change is that prvalues are no longer thought of as "materialized values" (with storage), but rather just as "instructions for how to intialize an object".
However, none of that has to do with your example, parts of which are colloquially known as "named return value optimization" ("NRVO"), but that's only half the story. The other half is that if the optimization (which would consist of constructing an value directly in the return value rather than "on the stack") is not actually done, then the local variable is considered an rvalue when it appears as the operand of a return statement.
Initially in the first C++11 this behaviour only worked that way when the type of the variable was exactly the return type of the function, but
CWG 1579 retroactively changed this behaviour so that now it has always been the behaviour as of C++11 that the returned variable is considered an rvalue, regardless of its type (and std::optional was a main motivation for this fix). For example, this now works:
std::optional<std::unique_ptr<int>> f() {
  auto p = std::make_unique<int>(1);
  return p;
}

In the time since C++17 there have been additional changes that make more things "considered an rvalue" when they appear as the expression in a return statement or throw expression, so generally there's a tendency to "try to move things when they can clearly no longer be used afterwards"; see P2266R3 adopted for C++23.
